# How to overwrite a pure virtual function with dynamic binding

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to solve exercise 7.3 in the Pitt-Francis text  https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-73132-2 regarding an abstract ODE class.

The abstract class is given as

```
class AbstractODESolver
{
private:
    ...
    
public:
    ....
    virtual double RightHandSide(double y, double t) = 0;
    virtual double SolveEquation() = 0;
    
};
```

The derived class is given as

```
class ForwardEuler: public AbstractODESolver
{
public:
     double RightHandSide(double y, double t);
     double SolveEquation();
};
```

How would one cast RightHandSide in ForwardEuler so that it may be defined at runtime?

In particular a main file could take the form

```
double RHS(double y, double t);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    
    AbstractODESolver* p_ODEs = new ForwardEuler;
        
    return 0;
}

double RHS(double y, double t)
{
    return 1+t;
}
```

and I would like to write something like

```
p_ODEs->RightHandSide = &RHS;`
```

to point to the function `RHS`.

Comment: That's not how member functions work – you implement `ForwardEuler::RightHandSide`. (And it's *override*, not "overwrite".)

Comment: Use the `RHS()` function in your implementation of  `ForwardEuler::RightHandSide()`?

Comment: BTW: you need to include the actual exercise in your question. Nobody's going to pay over 18 Euros just to see what it is.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks re. override. The point is to not have an explicit implementation of `ForwardEuler::RighthandSide`. We would like to define it at run time, as per the sketch of the main funtion. Is that clearer? Cheers, J

Comment: @john_matisse pass an appropriate `std::function` to `ForwardEuler`s constructor, and keep a member variable for it.

Comment: @molbdnilo, here's the exercise 

'Derive a class called FowardEulerSolver that allows the user to specify the function RightHandSide, and contains a method SolveEquation that uses the forward Euler method to calculate the values of yi as described above, and writes the values of ti and yi to file. '

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks. I am trying to avoid having a member function pointer in ForwardEuler, and override RightHandSide in the AbstractODESolver.

Comment: @john_matisse I meant you should keep a `std::function<double (double,double)>` member in your `ForwardEuler` class,  not the base. Also you should definitely still override `RightHandSide()`  in your implementation. _@kevin_ seems to have gotten my comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks. I misunderstood your first comment, I can see this now. Cheers J

Answer (score 2):

Give the `ForwardEuler` class a data member to store the function, and pass it in the constructor. The `RightHandSide` function will just call the function passed in.

```
class ForwardEuler: public AbstractODESolver
{
public:
    ForwardEuler(std::function<double(double, double)> rhs): rhs(rhs) {}
    double RightHandSide(double y, double t) { return rhs(y, t); }
    double SolveEquation();

private:
    std::function<double(double, double)> rhs;
};

...

double RHS(double y, double t);
AbstractODESolver* p_ODEs = new ForwardEuler(RHS);
```

Comment: Oh great. Of course, I hadn't thought about the constructor thanks!

Comment: Passing a plain old function pointer to `ForwardEuler` would be more efficient (although less flexible) than using `std::function`.

Comment: Here's my solution, which I think is the required solution given the techniques taught in the chapter.

```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that doesn't require `std::function`, which I think is the required solution given the techniques taught in the chapter.

(As per @Paul Sanders)

```
class ForwardEuler: public AbstractODESolver
{
public:
     ForwardEuler(double (*pRhs)(double, double));
     double RightHandSide(double y, double t);
     double SolveEquation();

private:
     double (*mRhs)(double y, double t);     
};
```

```
ForwardEuler::ForwardEuler(double (*pRhs)(double, double))
{
    mRhs = pRhs;
}

double ForwardEuler::RightHandSide(double y,double t)
{
    return (*mRhs)(y,t);
}
```

main function

```
double RHS(double y, double t);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    
    AbstractODESolver* p_ODEs = new ForwardEuler(RHS);
    std::cout<<(*p_ODEs).RightHandSide(1.0,1.0)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}

double RHS(double y, double t)
{
    return 1+t;
}
```